# lxc with nextcloud and nginx proxy: Unknown: POST Content-Length

Tags: php, nginx, lxc, nextcloud

I have two lxc containers. One is the proxy with nginx and this config:

```
server {

    server_name cloud.malte-kiefer.de;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass http://cloud.lxd;
    }

    real_ip_header proxy_protocol;
    set_real_ip_from 127.0.0.1;

    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 proxy_protocol; 
    listen 443 ssl http2 proxy_protocol; 
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/cloud.malte-kiefer.de/fullchain.cer; 
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/cloud.malte-kiefer.de/privkey.key; 


}
server {
    listen 80 proxy_protocol;
    listen [::]:80 proxy_protocol;

    server_name cloud.malte-kiefer.de;


    location / {
        return 301 https://cloud.malte-kiefer.de$request_uri;
    }

    return 404;
}
```

Then I have the cloud container with nextcloud with this config:

```
upstream php-handler {
    server unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    set $base /var/www/html;
    root /var/www/html;

    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name cloud.malte-kiefer.de;


    fastcgi_hide_header X-Powered-By;

    client_max_body_size 512M;
    fastcgi_buffers 64 4K;

    # Enable gzip but do not remove ETag headers
    gzip on;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_comp_level 4;
    gzip_min_length 256;
    gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private no_last_modified no_etag auth;
    gzip_types application/atom+xml application/javascript application/json application/ld+json application/manifest+json application/rss+xml application/vnd.geo+json application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf application/x-web-app-manifest+json application/xhtml+xml application/xml font/opentype image/bmp image/svg+xml image/x-icon text/cache-manifest text/css text/plain text/vcard text/vnd.rim.location.xloc text/vtt text/x-component text/x-cross-domain-policy;


        location = /robots.txt {
            allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location / {
        rewrite ^ /index.php;
    }

    location ~ ^\/(?:build|tests|config|lib|3rdparty|templates|data)\/ {
        deny all;
    }
    location ~ ^\/(?:\.|autotest|occ|issue|indie|db_|console) {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ ^\/(?:index|remote|public|cron|core\/ajax\/update|status|ocs\/v[12]|updater\/.+|oc[ms]-provider\/.+)\.php(?:$|\/) {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(\/.*|)$;
        set $path_info $fastcgi_path_info;
        try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $path_info;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
        fastcgi_param modHeadersAvailable true;
        fastcgi_param front_controller_active true;
        fastcgi_pass php-handler;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_request_buffering off;
    }

    location ~ ^\/(?:updater|oc[ms]-provider)(?:$|\/) {
        try_files $uri/ =404;
        index index.php;
    }

    location = /.well-known/carddav {
      return 301 https://cloud.malte-kiefer.de/remote.php/dav;
    }
    location = /.well-known/caldav {
      return 301 https://cloud.malte-kiefer.de/remote.php/dav;
    }

    location ~ \.(?:css|js|woff2?|svg|gif|map)$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php$request_uri;
        add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=15778463";
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains; preload;" always;

        # Optional: Don't log access to assets
        access_log off;
    }

    location ~ \.(?:png|html|ttf|ico|jpg|jpeg|bcmap)$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php$request_uri;
        # Optional: Don't log access to other assets
        access_log off;
    }
}
```

When I try to open the URL I see the installation page from nextcloud. When I enter information and send it reload from page and this in the nextcloud log:

> Unknown: POST Content-Length of 213 bytes exceeds the limit of 16
>   bytes at Unknown#0

This is the nginx log from the nextcloud container

> 2020/01/13 17:32:20 [error] 416#416: *8 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP
>   message: PHP Warning:  Unknown: POST Content-Length of 213 bytes
>   exceeds the limit of 16 bytes in Unknown on line 0" while reading
>   response header from upstream, client: 89.204.135.199, server:
>   cloud.malte-kiefer.de, request: "POST /index.php HTTP/1.0", upstream:
>   "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock:", host:
>   "cloud.malte-kiefer.de"

I check my PHP ini file:

```
root@cloud:~# grep -R "post_max_size" /etc/php/
/etc/php/7.3/fpm/php.ini:post_max_size = 16GB
/etc/php/7.3/cli/php.ini:post_max_size = 16GB
/etc/php/7.3/phpdbg/php.ini:post_max_size = 8M

root@cloud:~# grep -R "memory_limit" /etc/php/
/etc/php/7.3/fpm/pool.d/www.conf:;php_admin_value[memory_limit] = 32M
/etc/php/7.3/fpm/php.ini:memory_limit = 512M
/etc/php/7.3/cli/php.ini:memory_limit = 512M
/etc/php/7.3/phpdbg/php.ini:memory_limit = 128M
```

I can't find the issue. Maybe you guys can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it was a missconfig in the php.ini file.
I totally removed PHP vom the nextcloud container, reinstalled and it works now.